# Manifest.json is blocking script tags in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am getting this error when I'm trying to do `<script src="https://savehut.xyz/files/file.js"></script>` with a chrome extension:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://savehut.xyz/files/file.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I have this in my manifest.json file: (it's manifest v3 btw)

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "script-src": "'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/* https://savehut.xyz/* 'unsafe-inline';"
}
```

jsdelivr works, but savehut.xyz doesn't.

btw, the file location isn't /files/file.js, that's just an example thing

Comment: ManifestV3 extensions can't load remotely hosted scripts by design. And there's no such key in manifest.json as `"script-src"`, the supported keys are `extension_pages` and `sandbox`.